# ConfigurationManager gives a TypeInitializationException instantly

Tags: c#, xml, app-config, configurationmanager

I am making an application that needs to read its config file for its settings.

I've defined the settings in the **App_config** file like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="sswcomm" type="SSWAgent.SSWConfig" />
    <section name="folders" type="SSWAgent.SSWConfigFolderCollection" />
    <section name="folder" type="SSWAgent.SSWConfigFolderElement" />
  </configSections>
  <sswcomm id="SC_SSWTEST1" connectionInterval="5000">
    <folders>
      <folder id="OUTGOINGATOTEST2" enable="true" includeSubFolders="true" fromPath="C:\temp\a\NET\Outgoing_A" wildcard="*.*" recipientId="C_SSWTEST2" />
      <folder id="OUTGOINGBTOTEST3" enable="true" includeSubFolders="true" fromPath="C:\temp\a\NET\Outgoing_B" wildcard="*.*" recipientId="C_SSWTEST3" />
    </folders>
  </sswcomm>
</configuration>
```

And the C# code like so:

```
public sealed class SSWConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {
        private static SSWConfig settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("sswcomm") as SSWConfig;

        public static SSWConfig Settings
        {
            get { return settings; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("id", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "  ~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;’\"|\\", MinLength = 1, MaxLength = 256)]
        public string Id
        {
            get { return (string)this["id"]; }
            set { this["id"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("connectionInterval", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public int ConnectionInterval
        {
            get { return (int)this["connectionInterval"]; }
            set { this["connectionInterval"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("folders", IsDefaultCollection = true, IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
        public SSWConfigFolderCollection Folders
        {
            get { return base["folders"] as SSWConfigFolderCollection; }
        }

    }

    public sealed class SSWConfigFolderCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new SSWConfigFolderElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((SSWConfigFolderElement)element).Id;
        }

        new public SSWConfigFolderElement this[string Id]
        {
            get { return (SSWConfigFolderElement)base.BaseGet(Id); }
        }

        public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.BasicMap;
            }
        }

        public SSWConfigFolderElement this[int index]
        {
            get { return (SSWConfigFolderElement)base.BaseGet(index); }
        }

        protected override string ElementName
        {
            get
            {
                return "folder";
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class SSWConfigFolderElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("id", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "  ~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;’\"|\\", MinLength = 1, MaxLength = 256)]
        public string Id
        {
            get { return (string)base["id"]; }
            set { base["id"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("enable", DefaultValue = "true", IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
        public bool Enable
        {
            get { return (string)base["enable"] == "true"; }
            set { if (value) { base["enable"] = "true"; } else { base["enable"] = "false"; } }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("includeSubFolders", DefaultValue = "true", IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
        public bool IncludeSubFolders
        {
            get { return (string)base["includeSubFolders"] == "true"; }
            set { if (value) { base["includeSubFolders"] = "true"; } else { base["enable"] = "false"; } }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("fromPath", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
        public string FromPath
        {
            get { return (string)base["fromPath"]; }
            set { base["fromPath"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("wildcard", DefaultValue = "*.*", IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
        public string Wildcard
        {
            get { return (string)base["wildcard"]; }
            set { base["wildcard"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("recipientId", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = false, IsRequired = true)]
        [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "  ~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;’\"|\\", MinLength = 1, MaxLength = 256)]
        public string RecipientId
        {
            get { return (string)base["recipientId"]; }
            set { base["recipientId"] = value; }
        }
    }
```

Now, whenever I call `SSWConfig` and put it in a variable, I immediately get a `TypeInitializationException` exception. I think because the `GetSection` part returns `null`. Is this because I've made a mistake in the App.config file?

An app.config with nested elements is new for me, so it could be that I'm defining it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting my solution.

Apparently I was making it way harder than it actually is. I've started from scratch and after some modifications my settings get read.

Another error that I had is that I never actually read the configuration file (oops), thinking that it would happen automatically when calling the Configuration class.

Class:

```cs
// <sswcomm></sswcomm> settings
public class SSWConfigSSWComm : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("id")]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return (string)this["id"]; }
        set { this["id"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("connectionInterval")]
    public int ConnectionInterval
    {
        get { return (int)this["connectionInterval"]; }
        set { this["connectionInterval"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("toPath")]
    public string ToPath
    {
        get { return (string)this["toPath"]; }
        set { this["toPath"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("folders")]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(SSWConfigFolderElement), AddItemName = "folder")]
    public SSWConfigFolderElementCollection sswConfigFolders
    {
        get { return (SSWConfigFolderElementCollection)base["folders"]; }
    }
}

// <folder> settings
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(SSWConfigFolderElement))]
public class SSWConfigFolderElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    new public SSWConfigFolderElement this[string name]
    {
        get { return (SSWConfigFolderElement)base.BaseGet(name); }
    }

    public SSWConfigFolderElement this[int index]
    {
        get { return (SSWConfigFolderElement)base.BaseGet(index); }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new SSWConfigFolderElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((SSWConfigFolderElement)element).Id;
    }
}

public class SSWConfigFolderElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("id")]
    public string Id
    {
        get { return (string)base["id"]; }
        set { base["id"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("enable")]
    public bool Enable
    {
        get { return (string)base["enable"] == "true"; }
        set { if (value) { base["enable"] = "true"; } else { base["enable"] = "false"; } }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("includeSubFolders")]
    public bool IncludeSubFolders
    {
        get { return (string)base["includeSubFolders"] == "true"; }
        set { if (value) { base["includeSubFolders"] = "true"; } else { base["enable"] = "false"; } }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("fromPath")]
    public string FromPath
    {
        get { return (string)base["fromPath"]; }
        set { base["fromPath"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("wildcard")]
    public string Wildcard
    {
        get { return (string)base["wildcard"]; }
        set { base["wildcard"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("recipientId")]
    [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "  ~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;’\"|\\", MinLength = 1, MaxLength = 256)]
    public string RecipientId
    {
        get { return (string)base["recipientId"]; }
        set { base["recipientId"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Gathering the data

```cs
        Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        SSWConfigSSWComm sc = (SSWConfigSSWComm)conf.GetSection("sswcomm");

        string Id = sc.Id;
        long lngInterval = sc.ConnectionInterval;
        string toPath = sc.ToPath;
        SSWConfigFolderElementCollection fec = sc.sswConfigFolders;
        foreach (SSWConfigFolderElement fe in fec)
        {
            string fromPath = fe.FromPath;
            string wildcard = fe.Wildcard;
            bool includeSubFolders = fe.IncludeSubFolders;
            string recipientId = fe.RecipientId;
            sp.GetFiles(Id, recipientId, fromPath, toPath, wildcard, includeSubFolders);
        }
```

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.